# How to run MSSQL container with Full-Text Search on M1 Mac?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, apple-m1

The current image I am using for MSSQL is the Azure SQL Edge image and according to official docs, this image doesn't support Full-Text Search.

Since the above mentioned image doesn't support Full-Text Search, is there another way to run the MSSQL container with the Full-Text Search on M1 Mac?

Comment: You don't. Not until Microsoft releases a version of the full SQL Server Data engine that can run on ARM architecture.

Comment: I expect Docker will get [Rosetta 2 support](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/384) in place before Microsoft produces M1 builds of SQL Server for Linux/Docker.